# Finding the range of $y$ when $y = \frac{1}{x^2}$ for negative values of $x$......

Tags: inequality

//this question was solved, thank you to all those who gave answers and commented

So, here's the exact question:

> Find the range of $y$ for $y = \frac{1}{x^2}$ when $-6 < x <6$

I started of something really simple, I first thought of $-1 < x < 1$
$$\frac{1}{-1} < \frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{1}$$ 
which equals $$-1 < \frac{1}{x} < 1$$
now squaring the inequality, we should get, $$1 < y < 1$$
But isn't $1 < 1$ weird? So ignoring the negative values of $\frac{1}{x}$, $$0 \leq y < 1$$
Because, well, thinking a bit about it, won't the squares of all the negative numbers be equal to that of all the postitive numbers...?
To check whether my answer truely satisfies the inequality,
take $x = -0.5$, we get $y = 4$ which is NOT in the range of $y$ I found out..... (refer doubt 1)

Now, I tried to do the same thing with $-6 < x < 6$,
$$\frac{-1}{6} < \frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{6}$$
$$\frac{1}{36} < y < \frac{1}{36}$$
Which simplifies to,
$$0 \leq y < \frac{1}{36}$$
hence $$y \in [0 , \frac{1}{36})$$
As I did earlier too, take $x = -5$ , we get $y = \frac{1}{25}$ 
As I had noticed earlier.....$\frac{1}{25}$ is not in range of $y$ I found out....

Doubt 1: Why is this happening? Where did I go wrong? Was it when I assumed $0 \leq y < 1$ ? 
Doubt 2: What should be the value of $x$ so that $y = 0$? or should $0 < y$ instead of $0 \leq y$? 
Doubt 3: I tried to first do $(-6)^2 < x^2 < (6)^2$ 
 which is similar to $0 \leq x^2 < 36$ 
which is similar to $\frac{1}{0} \leq y < \frac{1}{36}$ 
 Why am I encountering $\frac{1}{0}$ ?

Can anyone please help me in this? Any suggestions/hints would help! Also question suggestions/edits are gladly welcomed! Formatting edits/suggestions are gladly welcomed too!
PS: Couldn't find a similar problem to this.....so hopefully it is not a....duplicate?

Comment: @Anne squares are always positive except being zero, right? So I thought to take the reciprocal immediately after I found the range for $x^2$

Comment: $a<b<c$ neither implies $a^2<b^2<c^2$ nor $1/a<1/b<1/c.$ The only reliable rule is: if $0<x<y$ then $x^2<y^2$ and $1/x>1/y.$

Comment: That is not what you did. You first took the reciprocal (with mistake). $-1<x<1$ does not at all imply $-1<\frac1x<1.$ If $0<x<1$ then $\frac1x>1,$ and if $-1<x<0$ then $0<-x<1$ hence $\frac1{-x}>1,$ i.e. $\frac1x<-1.$

Comment: ohh so are you talking about what i did in my third doubt? like i first squared x then i took its reciprocal @anne

Comment: No, as I told you, I was talking about your whole post  where you first took the reciprocal.

Comment: I completely get you, but, i do not get it mathetically.....can you still explain why 1/x is not -1 < 1/x < 1?

Comment: I did:  please see my detailed two first comments.

Comment: I am sorry @anne I did not look at the signs seriously, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be thinking that

1. For any real numbers $a,b$, if $a<b$, then $a^2<b^2$.
2. For any real numbers $a,b$, if $a<b$, then $\frac{1}{a} < \frac{1}{b}$.

When explicitly stated like this,
it should not be difficult to see that these are not true.
Try to find some counterexamples yourself.

For example, if $a=-3$ and $b=1$, then $a<b$ and $a^2>b^2$.
If $a=1$ and $b=2$, then $a<b$ and $\frac{1}{a}>\frac{1}{b}$.

What *is* true is the following:

> For any *positive* real numbers $a,b$, we have $a<b$ if and only if $a^2<b^2$ if and only if $\frac{1}{a}>\frac{1}{b}$.
> For any *negative* real numbers $a,b$, we have $a<b$ if and only if $a^2>b^2$ if and only if $\frac{1}{a}<\frac{1}{b}$.

This is true because the function $x^2$ is strictly increasing only on positive real numbers,
and the function $\frac{1}{x}$ is strictly decreasing only on negative real numbers.
For negative numbers, $x^2$ is strictly decreasing, and $\frac{1}{x}$ is strictly increasing.

---

This should answer most of your doubts.
In general, when you see something like $1<1$,
you know you messed up (unless you are doing proof by contradiction).
You should stop immediately and check your solution.

Back to your original question

> Determine the range of $y=\frac{1}{x^2}$ for $-6<x<6$.

First, $y$ is undefined for $x=0$.
You should exclude $x=0$.

Now, we know that we should not consider positive and negative numbers at once.
Let's first consider $0<x<6$.
The statement $0<x<6$ is really two separate inequalities: $0<x$ and $x<6$.
Now, we want to take the reciprocal, but we cannot do it for $0<x$
because we cannot divide by $0$.
Do it for $x<6$ and we have $$\frac{1}{x}>\frac{1}{6}.$$
Then we want to square this. Both sides are positive, so
$$
\frac{1}{x^2}>\frac{1}{36}.
$$
This shows that if $0<x<6$, then $\frac{1}{x^2}>\frac{1}{36}$.
Now we simply reverse the above proof to show that
if $\frac{1}{x^2}>\frac{1}{36}$, then $0<x<6$ (both directions need to be shown in order to prove that the range of $y$ corresponding to $0<x<6$ is $y>\frac{1}{36}$).

Now, we turn to the case where $-6<x<0$.
Well, you can do it once again, flipping all the signs,
but notice that $\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{(-x)^2}$,
so the range corresponding to $-6<x<0$ is the same as $0<x<6$.
Thus, we can conclude that the desired range is $y>\frac{1}{36}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed solution!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x)=y=1/x^2$ cannot be zero or negative, so it's better to say what is the range if $x\in (-6,6)\setminus\{0\}$. Here $f$ is an even function, i.e. $f(-x)=f(x)$, so to find the range we can just consider $x\in(0,6)$. Now note that $f$ is a continuous decreasing function on the interval $(0,6)$.

Comment: okay, does this still affect what i had found out @dyako ? EDIT: I cannot understand basically where I went wrong from your solution, although your solution is correct

Comment: @CuckooBeats, well if $x$ approaches zero, what's gonna happen for $y$?

Comment: an $\infty$ ? does that mean y is actually increasing

Comment: @CuckooBeats, I guess we can say that if we move backward along the x axis, but actually it is decreasing from ∞ to $1/36$

Comment: oh okay, i get it now

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you do not know the consequences of taking the reciprocal of an  inequality.

Consider your orignial inequality: $-1<x<1$, we only look at $x<1$. If we take the reciprocal, we need to switch the sign: $\frac1x>1$ for example $\frac12<1\implies\frac21>1$. Similarly, $-1<x\implies \frac1x<-1$. So the original inequality implies that $\frac1x>1$ OR $\frac1x<-1$.

Squaring the inequality is a little bit trickier. For $\frac1x<-1$, we would switch the signs to get $\frac1{x^2}>1$. But for $\frac1x>1$ we would not do that since $1$ is positive, we would also get $\frac1{x^2}>1$.

Can you try doing this with $6$?

> Ans: $y>\frac1{36}$

Comment: I am utterly sorry for this. I had completely forgotten to reverse the inequality, thank you!